# CloudKit - partialFailure and limitExceeded

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckerror

**Summary**

In `CloudKit` would like to know all the possible `CKError.Code` possible for a `.partialFailure`.

Presently I am only handling the following `CKError.Code` for a partialFailure.

**Assumptions:**

1. `.serverRecordChanged`  //Only applicable while saving records
2. `.zoneNotFound` //Only applicable while fetching zones
3. `.unknownItem`  //Only applicable while fetching items
4. `.batchRequestFailed` //Only applicable while saving records in custom zone

---

- Technically partialFailure can throw any `CKError`, but logically partialFailure is a failure at the item level and not at the operation level so `partialFailure` would not contain operation level errors such as `networkUnavailable` / `badContainer` / `badDatabase`.
- Please refer to see how `partialFailure` is handled -  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CloudKitShare/Introduction/Intro.html (Search for `handlePartialError`) -

**Questions:**

1. For `partialFailure`, are the above stated the only possible error
   codes ?
2. Are the errors `serverRecordChanged`, `zoneNotFound`,
   `unknownItem` only possible as part of `partialFailure` error ? (Would
   the error returned by the completion handler not directly contain
   `serverRecordChanged`, `zoneNotFound`, `unknownItem` but only
   `partialFailure` error may contain them ?)
3. Are my comments regarding
   when each of the above error correct ? (Only applicable while...)
4. Is `limitExceeded` error thrown for `CKFetch` operations and `CKModify` operations or is it only
   applicable for `CKModify` operations ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Partial Failure means that some of the CKRecords involved in an operations has failed, and maybe others finished without problem. Error could be one from the CKError structure
2. No. Those errors could happend in a CKDatabase.save ot CKDatadabe fetch operation.
3. +- ;-)
4. *limitExceeded* could happend on save or modify. For Fetching It's iCloud server which informs clients (you) when are more records waiting to be fetched. For example, the [CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckfetchnotificationchangesoperation) has the property [moreComing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckfetchnotificationchangesoperation/1515108-morecoming) which indicates that you need to make another fetch operation.